# the type or namespace name Web does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft'

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7

I recovered an old WP7 project, and I can't build it because I can't find Microsoft.Web
at this line

using Microsoft.Web.Media.SmoothStreaming;

Unfortunately I try to add a reference (Microsoft.Web.Media.SmoothStreaming) but I can't find this reference...

I am on Visual Studio 2012

Any idea?

Thank you